# Azure Firewall - Can't NAT with internal IP as destination?

Tags: firewall, azure

Today on my on-premise environment I'm using Checkpoint as the firewall and I was the option to configure NAT rules with the following:

"Original Source" - "Original Destination" - "Original Port" - "Translated Destination" - "Translated port"

and I can set "Translated Destination" as internal IP.

on Azure Firewall DNAT rules I can't configure internal IP, I can only configure my Firewall Public IP.

That means that if I have multiple services using the same port, I won't be able to translate to them.

I guess 1 solution will be to configure a reverse proxy like nginx to do the work?

Comment: "_That means that if I have multiple services using the same port, I won't be able to translate to them._" Yes, that is one of the limitations of the NAPT version of NAT. The packet destination is the outside address, and you can forward a protocol port number to a single inside device.

Comment: I understand, Do you think using a reverse proxy like nginx can help? Thank you